# I need to write a script for Eiskalt DC++ in QTscript. How do I start learning to use Qtscript?

Tags: qt, qtscript

I do not know Javascript and have never used Qt. I do use c++ but I don't think that is much help? It is a pretty simple script but I can't find any tutorial etc for Qtscript.

Answer (score 1):

Qt's own documentation is a good place to start. Try [Making Applications Scriptable](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/scripting.html) and [Qt Script Examples](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/examples-script.html).